# A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: java, php

I have here a java code, what I'm trying to do is create a php equivalent of this:

```
 String text = "Sample Text";
                int key = 6;
        for(int i =0; i < text.length();i++) {
            char ch = text.charAt(i);
            ch -= key;
                        System.out.print(ch);
        }
```

Output:

M[gjf_N_rn

This is my php code. I got an Error "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered".

```
$key = 6;
    $text = 'Sample Text';
    for($i = 0;$i < strlen($text);$i++){
        $char = $text{$i};
        $char -= $key;
        echo $char;
    }
```

I certainly get an error here.

```
    $char -= $key;
```

Comment: OT: The curly-brace syntax (`$text{$i}`) has been deprecated since PHP version 7.4.0, and removed altogether in version 8.0.0. Use square-brace syntax instead (`$text[$i]`).

Comment: Regarding your problem, do PHP really have a "character" type, or is it just a kind of string? And if it has character then it clearly isn't a generic integer type as in Java. You need to convert the character to its corresponding encoded integer value (and back to a character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$key = 6;
    $text = 'Sample Text';
    for($i = 0;$i < strlen($text);$i++){
        $char = $text{$i};
        $charcode = ord($char);
        $charcode -=$key;
        //echo $charcode.'-';
        if($charcode<0) {$charcode+=256;}
        $charcode%=256;
        $char = chr($charcode);
        echo $char;
    }
```